# JS ES5 OOP: private instance member via get/set in constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, private, getter-setter, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to create a constructor in a namespace (IIFE module pattern) that has a **private instance member** of sort that can only be changed via set/get methods.
I use an IIFE that returns get/set functions that create a closure on the data, and return the get/set to the instance property.
From my testing the pattern seems to work; meaning the members are private and can be accessed through the get/set only.

A) do you think this is true?

B) Are these good patterns or are there better alternatives (in ES5)?

Structure and Fiddle:

```
IIFE module -> constructor-> IIFE that returns get/set
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sblast/x22fsLnb/1/)

Thanks ahead of time

```
//namespace 
var computerModule = (function() {
  //function constructor 
  function Computer(CPUMemory, diskMemory, CPUModel, price, warrantyInYears) {
    this.CPUMemory = CPUMemory;
    this.diskMemory = diskMemory;
    this.CPUModel = CPUModel;
  }
  Computer.prototype.buyAccessories = buyAccessories;
  Computer.prototype.print = print;
  Computer.prototype.toString = toString;

  function buyAccessories() {

  }

  function print() {
    console.log(this.toString());
  }

  function toString() {
    return `CPUMemory: ${this.CPUMemory},diskMemory: ${this.diskMemory}, CPUModel: ${this.CPUModel}, price: ${price}, warrantyInYears: ${warrantyInYears}`;
  }

  //return constructor
  return {
    Computer
  }
})();

//namespace 
var laptopComputerModule = (function() {
  //constructor
  function Laptop(CPUMemory, diskMemory, CPUModel, price, warrantyInYears, ChargingTime, ) {

    computerModule.Computer.call(this, CPUMemory, diskMemory, CPUModel, price,
      warrantyInYears);

    //trying to create a member that cannot be directly changed - need feeback
    Object.defineProperty(this, "BatteryChargingTime", {
      value: (function() {
        //private variable
        var BatteryChargingTime;
        //constructor init
        BatteryChargingTime = ChargingTime;

        function get() {
          return BatteryChargingTime;
        }

        function set(arg) {
          BatteryChargingTime = arg;
        }

        return { //functions create closuers on variables in this function, keeping its scope intact
          get,
          set
        }
      }()),
      writable: false,
      configurable: true
    })
  }
}());
```

Comment: Please include the code in your question.

Comment: Question: why is it so important to make the member "absolutely private" and does that justify this bending over backwards?

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to put an IIFE inside the constructor. The constructor `function` already provides a scope.

```
function Laptop(CPUMemory, diskMemory, CPUModel, price, warrantyInYears, ChargingTime, ) {
  computerModule.Computer.call(this, CPUMemory, diskMemory, CPUModel, price, warrantyInYears);

  this.BatteryChargingTime = {
    get: function() {
      return ChargingTime;
    },
    set: function(arg) {
      ChargingTime = arg;
    }
  }
}
```

Apart from that, it's a totally standard pattern. (Of course there's no point in making a "private" member that can be arbitrarily set by its setter method).

Comment: Can you explain the closure and how it relates to the instance?
The get function 'closes' on a variable that's on the constructor, keeping its scope. The function that does the closing lives on an object that's on the instance?